# User Current Location Not Find

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In one of my Project I Have to send Users current Location to web server in the Appdelegate . It is working fine when the user click on the Ok button of the alert shown to get permission from the user.But at the first time when I running the application the permission alert is showing late after comming to rootview Controller.Meanwhile the latitude and longitude getting the cllocation is 0.00000f.How can I get permission forcefully at appdelegate Or forcefully get users location.

Second think If the user deny to axis his location.The alert is not showing other Time.In that case also the latitude and longitude getting the cllocation is 0.00000f.How I show permission alert 2 or more than two time in same application.I hope you will understand my question.

Happy coding

Comment: r u running in a device or a simulator?

Comment: i m running in device bro..

Answer (score 0):

as per your scenerio you have to set the `CLLocationManager` before the set the `rootViewController` of Window in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

for your **second thing** apple with default asked only once the alert if user give permission then call `CLLocationManagerDelegate method`

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

and get the lat and long of your current location do your stuff with it .if user has denied location services then you have to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905189/check-if-a-user-allows-the-app-to-use-their-location?rq=1).

Comment: alert will so once try to fully reinstall it then you get it .

Comment: Can yo favor me some think.What can i do if the user deny the permission.I have to show his/her location.I give alert to user to reinstall the application

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the `AppDelegate`'s interface.

In order to start CLLocationManager to fetch location you must set some properties of CLLocationManager class. For this implement the following code fragment:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Location manager settings
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

   // Your code for rootViewController settings here
}
```

Then implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method as follows

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations  {
    CLLocation *userLocation = [locations lastObject];
}
```

The `userLocation` object will be the user's current location.